# Slick Carousel how to go to a slide and give it focus based on href

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slick.js

I have an issue with Slick Slider:

1. Based on href set Current Slide
2. Based on href set Focus
3. Based on href set GotoSlide
4. When dragging or click on arrow don't change the current slide status

I have tried many methods to make it work, but they've all failed.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/kelvinspaces/pen/JjXopVa

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('#DailyLifeStyleTabs').slick(DailyLifeStyleTabs());
    GetActiveMenu('');
    function GetActiveMenu(path) {
        if (path != "") {
            var pathName = path;
            return;
        }
        var pathName = $(location).attr('pathname');
        var tabindex = $('#DailyLifeStyleTabs .slick-slide div li a[href="' + pathName + '"]').parents('.slick-slide').data("slick-index");
        $('#DailyLifeStyleTabs').slick("slickGoTo", tabindex);
        $('#DailyLifeStyleTabs .slick-slide').removeClass('slick-current');
        $('#DailyLifeStyleTabs .slick-slide div li a[href="' + pathName + '"]').parents('.slick-slide').addClass('slick-current');
    }
});
```

Slide Settings:

```
//Daily Tabs Settings
function DailyLifeStyleTabs() {
    return {
        dots: false,
        slidesToShow: 7,
        slidesToScroll: 7,
        infinite: true,
        arrows: true,
        //focusOnChange: false
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="DailyLifeStyleTabs" class="daily-lifestyle-tabs">
  <li><a href="/DailyLifeStyle/NewMums">New Mums</a></li>
  <li><a href="/DailyLifeStyle/CreativeHobbies">Creative Hobbies</a></li>
  <li><a href="/DailyLifeStyle/JustHitTheBall">Just Hit The Ball</a></li>
  <li><a href="/DailyLifeStyle/CycleMania">Cycle Mania</a></li>
  <li><a href="/DailyLifeStyle/StayWarm">Stay Warm</a></li>
  <li><a href="/DailyLifeStyle/RestRelax">Rest Relax</a></li>
  <li><a href="/DailyLifeStyle/PetLover">Pet Lover</a></li>
  <li><a href="/DailyLifeStyle/HouseKeeping">House Keeping</a></li>
  <li><a href="/DailyLifeStyle/WaterSportsLover">Water Sports Lover</a></li>
  <li><a href="/DailyLifeStyle/HygieneMustHaves">Hygiene Must Haves</a></li>
  <li><a href="/DailyLifeStyle/ExtremeSports">Extreme Sports</a></li>
  <li><a href="/DailyLifeStyle/HighStreetFashion">High Street Fashion</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That CodePen is not going to work, as your anchor tags have no `href` attribute to use as the `pathName` in your JavaScript. Perhaps you could replace your markup with the HTML that's generated by your page.

Comment: Hi, i have updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `slideToscroll: 1` and `infinite: true`, all the problem solved.

```
//Daily Tabs Settings
function DailyLifeStyleTabs() {
    return {
        dots: false,
        slidesToShow: 10,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: true,
        arrows: true,
        lazyLoad: 'progressive',
    }
};
```

[image]